# Interviewing a sound designer

Tags: sound-design, interviews

I have an assignment for my careers in music class from Cal Poly Pomona. I have to interview someone in the field I wish to be in after graduation.(Sound Design) I have been looking online for people near the Pomona to LA area and found David Farmer is in Burbank and a few others. I need to interview someone who does sound design professionally and has some good credits.If you have someone in mind that is open for interviews and is available between now and the end of November it would help a lot? Also what should I ask?
Thanks.

Comment: David Farmer lives in the SF Bay Area (at least I think he still does).  It's been many years since he's lived in SoCal.

What field are you looking to get into?  Film, Games, TV, etc?  There are a lot of people in the LA area working in sound.

Comment: I would like to do film, but games are also very interesting. And yeah if anyone on here who is professionally doing sound design and lives in the LA area, I would love a chance to interview as many pros as possible. So far everyone on this site has been very helpful and has really good advice. Thanks everyone. If you are open for a 15-20 minute interview and you do film or games sound design please let me know. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago there seemed to be an industry-wide initiative to promote sound design and raise awareness of it as a discipline. I have a feeling that's still going on, so I'd trust you stand more chance than you might think. Also, the people I've gotten in touch with so far have been quite responsive. Don't forget, this site is full of industry folk too :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you myself, as I'm based in the UK but I can wholeheartedly recommend chatting with Dave Farmer if you can, as not only is he really bloody lovely, but to watch him at work as I've had the privilege to do back on LOTR, is something to behold .